# What is the difference between a Tomcat8 Server linked with Eclipse and one on a Linux server according to Memory Management?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8

I have a question about the Memory Management between a Tomcat8 Server linked with Eclipse and one on a Linux server.

My problem is, that the WebApp on the remote creates a lot of memory usage over time and the local one doesn't.

My other question: [JSON Builder cause memory leak in Tomcat8 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802394/json-builder-cause-memory-leak-in-tomcat8-application)

This screenshot is from the one which is linked with eclipse.
[image]

And this one is on my Linux server.
[image]

Both Tomcat server have the same version 8.0.14 and also Java 8.

These are the settings from the remote one:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Djava.security.policy=/tmp/tools.policy
-Xms256m
-Xmx3500m
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat8/endorsed
-Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8
-Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp
```

and this from the local one:

```
-Dcatalina.base=C:\dev\java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
-Dcatalina.home=C:\dev\Tomcat8
-Dwtp.deploy=C:\dev\java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\dev\Tomcat8\endorsed
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true

--Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

--Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
```

**Update**:
Here I have 2 more images about the problem.
This is the Eclipse One:
[image]

And this is the Linux One:
[image]

You see, the Eclipse one produce less memory usage over the time. Both server run about 2 hours now.

Comment: How long is your "eclipse" one running? And are you driving the same *traffic* against both instances?

Comment: Both running about 2hours now. And about the traffic I can only say, I am doing the same things. So it should be the same traffic. And I've edited my question

Comment: Is the totally available memory on the machines the same? With more available memory the JVM may use more memory to reduce the number of garbage collection cycles.

Comment: The Xmx flag is set on the remote one to 3500M and on the local machine to 3072M. But the overall memory is not the same. On the remote I have 4096M and on my local machine I have 32768M